# How to use "docker with pipeline" in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins I would like to [use docker with pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).
That documentation says:

> Starting with Pipeline versions 2.5 and higher, Pipeline has built-in
> support for interacting with Docker

Our Jenkins is using version `2.305 (2021-08-03)` right now. The latest version of jenkins currently is `2.340 (2022-03-22)`.

**How can I find the version of "Pipeline" used at our system?**

I found quite a few installed plugins called "Pipeline: ..." with various versions. Which one should be 2.5 in order to make the docker feature available?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found it:

https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator/

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-aggregator-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

The Plugin was simply not installed at all. (Only many of it's dependencies where installed independently.)